# ¿Como verificar la conexión a Google Drive?

Tags: android, google-drive

**Mi problema:** Actualmente me encuentro en la situación de poder verificar si el usuario se ha enlazado correctamente a `Google Drive`. En otras palabras, realizar un sistema de comprobación de enlace. Este problema surge porque me he percatado que algunas veces por falta de conexión a Internet o errores en los servicios de `Google` ocurren errores en el enlace y no es enlazado el usuario, y si no se enlaza este usuario ocurre un error al tratar de realizar otro método. Ejemplo: crear una carpeta.

Mi actual solución era un método que brinda la la clase `GoogleApiClient`:

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient;
apiClient.isConnected()
```

Este método devuelve si el usuario esta conectado a los servicios de `Google` pero en plural y no en singular por lo tanto no me permite verificar específicamente `Google Drive`.

Si saben como lograr mi objetivo, estaré encantado de escuchar o mas bien leer sus comentarios y respuestas. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Para ese objetivo son los métodos **onConnected()** y **onConnectionFailed()**...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La API de Android te permite conectarte específicamente a Google Drive. Aunque **por ahora** tiene algunas limitaciones como indica la nota de más abajo. Puse **por ahora** en negrita porque así lo dice Google, y podemos interpretar que piensan ampliar el alcance de la API.

### Cómo conectar y autorizar la API de Google Drive para Android

La autorización para la API de Google Drive para Android es gestionada por GoogleApiClient. Normalmente se crea en el método `onCreate()` de una actividad.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

Después de crear el cliente, debes conectarlo para que se produzca la autorización:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Si el usuario no ha autorizado previamente la aplicación, se invocará la devolución de llamada `onConnectionFailed()`. La devolución de llamada debe comprobar la presencia de un Intent pendiente para resolver el error e iniciar la actividad. Se le pedirá al usuario que autorice la aplicación a acceder a sus archivos en Drive.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}
```

El método `onActivityResult()` de la actividad será llamado al finalizar. Si el resultado es `RESULT_OK`, la actividad debe llamar a `connect()` de nuevo para establecer la conexión.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        ...
        case RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

> **Nota**: actualmente, la API de Google Drive para Android sólo admite los
>   ámbitos de autorización drive.file y drive.appfolder. Si su aplicación
>   requiere permisos o funciones adicionales que aún no están disponibles
>   en Drive API de Android, debe utilizar el Cliente Java de API de
>   Google.

#### Otra solución posible

Si el alcance que da actualmente la API de Google Drive para Android no es suficiente para lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar la API de Java como la usabas antes, pero restringiendo la conexión sólo a Google Drive, sea:

- a. Enviando solamente SCOPES relativos a Google Drive en la conexión, o bien:
- b. Configurando en la Consola de Desarrolladores de Google un proyecto que sólo de acceso a Google Drive y a ningún otro servicio de Google y conectarte con esas credenciales.

Así, al verificar la conexión estarás seguro de que estás conectado sólo a Google Drive.

---

Fuente: [Google Drive API para Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth?hl=es-419)

Comment: Amigo excelente ayuda pero una pregunta de donde sale la variable o constante RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE, que me da error al implementarla.Gracias

Comment: Creo que es un error de Google. Según esta pregunta (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24420949/5587982), han hecho cambios en la API. La constante se puede cambiar por `REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION`. Prueba a ver si con eso no te da error.

Comment: Gracias su ayuda ha sido beneficiosa.

Comment: En realidad RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE puede ser defidino simplemetne como  private static final int RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE = 1; y dentro de onActivityResult revisas si requestCode ==1 y posteriormente si  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

Answer (score 2):

> **¿Como verificar la conexión a Google Drive?**

Esto puede ser sencillo, tu clase debe implementar [**ConnectionCallbacks**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) y       **[OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)**,

[**ConnectionCallbacks**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) tiene los métodos:

```
  @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

    }
```

mientras que   **[OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)** tiene el método:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

}
```

> me encuentro en la situación de poder verificar si el usuario se ha
>   enlazado correctamente a Google Drive.

Como ejemplo definimos una variable para almacenar el status:

```
 private boolean isAPIConnected;
```

Si la conexión fallo podemos determinar que se llamo el método:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {     
    isAPIConnected= false; //NO REALIZO CONEXION!
    }
}
```

en cambio si la conexión se realizo con exito se llama el método:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {     
    isAPÏConnected = true; //SI REALIZO CONEXION!
}
```

Si existe conexión, puedes conectarte sin problema y realizar operaciones a tu Google Drive:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]